# Determine lead acid battery safe float charge level for a range of state-of-charge

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid

**My question:**

I want to know how to determine the highest safe voltage for a given SoC (state-of-charge). Or for a given float charge voltage, determine the lowest safe SoC.

**Helpful hints to the solution:**

In the answer to [this previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83661/stopping-criterion-of-lead-acid-battery-charging-operation-with-smps), Olin succinctly states:

> Unless the battery is quite low, it can be charged by holding its
> voltage at the "float charge" level. That is usually 13.6 to 14.0 V
> for a 12 V (6 cell) battery. [...] For a really depleted lead-acid
> battery, you have to be careful to limit its charge current.

The links below have been invaluable to me. I don't know if my question is dependent on any particular lead acid battery, or can be roughly determined by generic properties of lead acid batteries.

- [SLA charging basics](http://www.powerstream.com/SLA.htm)
- [Charging Lead Acid](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery)
- [Lead Acid SoC vs Voltage](http://www.zetatalk4.com/docs/Batteries/FAQ/State_Of_Charge_Ver_Voltage_2004+.pdf)
- [Internal resistance vs Capacity](http://www.buchmann.ca/article25-page1.asp)
- [Battery Performance Characteristics](http://www.mpoweruk.com/performance.htm)
- [Charging VRLA](https://www.cdtechno.com/pdf/ref/41_2128_0212.pdf)

(No wonder, then, why my head is gassing)

**Background (if necessary):**

The problem I'm actually trying to solve is designing a generic charging circuit which connects between a solar cell and a battery connected to a vehicle. The current draw by the vehicle at any time is unknown. Ideally, the capacity of the battery will not be known. Therefore, Olin's suggestion of limiting the charge current is not really an option, as this would be battery-specific. Saying that, The solar cells will be modest - probably at most 5A at a working voltage around the battery's float charge voltage. And the battery's capacity would be in the expected range for vehicles; so perhaps between 30Ah and 100Ah.

Obviously the charging circuit is not to replace the vehicle's charging system. Nor is it even to keep the battery at full charge - but to stop the battery emptying, as far as possible, while the vehicle's engine is not running. So while current is being drawn by the radio, lights, or accessories, or while the battery is relatively empty from said current draw, the solar cells would kick in.

Sorry for the lengthy question!

Comment: Usually those numbers are provided in the batteries datasheets. These usually contain some information about the max charge current that you want to obey too.

Comment: Thanks - but I was hoping to come to conclusions for my question based on generic properties of lead acid batteries - e.g. using the graphs on the links provided

Comment: Since there are no generic lead acid batteries, they can not have generic properties.

Comment: Yet vehicles and their batteries are largely cross compatible? I mean generic vehicle batteries, the VRLA kind, not SLA or AGM or others.

Comment: That is because you use the same kind of battery for them, e.g. starter batteries (as opposed to e.g. traction batteries, deep cycle etc.). But even there you have lots of performance differences. It is just that lead acids are quite forgiving for being battered. Most are fine with an initial C/10 current limit followed by some 13.xV constant voltage forever (read: until they break). Note that for different cars you already have different Ah requirements, which also means different C/10 which usually the alternator is sized for.

Comment: Agreed. Yet Olin's statement about float charging voltages for  batteries that aren't "really depleted" is undisputed? I am just trying to take that line of thought as far as it can go.

Comment: As I said, most are fine with 13.xV (as long as current and heat are not exceeded) but the exact value largely depends on how the battery is built (luquid,gel, solid etc.) and therefore a manufacturer gives a recommendation which (we all hope) is for a maximum lifetime. Another old rule of thumb: if it bubbles or melts, it was too much.

Comment: Thank you for helping me talk this one out. I think my solution, then, would be to take the worst case, e.g. compare maximum charge currents for depleted batteries of different manufacturers' 30Ah specs. Still, I will wait for answers by others, in case someone has a better approach, or an insight into refining Olin's statement for generic starter batteries etc.

Comment: 13.7V is the accepted lead acid float voltage at 25C, based on electrochemical considerations. Much above that is liable to be unwise in an unknown number of cases. There re variations in electrode materials (calcium, ...) construction styles (Gates cylindrical) and quite a few more that change ideal operating conditions. While you are designing a charger that does not care about battery capacity and type you could design clothes and shoes which fit all people without change - it may be easier. ....

Comment: .... Battery university have other relevant references to go with the one you cited. Note that a battery that is floated at 13.7V will need an occasional boost charge to 14.x to keep it full charged.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need an intelligent charger (micro controller based with a custom program to handle inputs from V&A meters, solar charge controller, & a power regulator).

Common methods of determining the SOC of a 12V(nominal) battery aren't very accurate.  Most often people use a generic table that shows V & SOC %.  The problem with that data set is that it applies to a new/good battery and as a battery ages & deteriorates the internal battery resistance increases, charge capacity decreases, & charge rate decreases (i.e. the charge rate of an aged battery is slower at a specific voltage than a new battery)--so you can't rely on it as a reliable method to charge a battery with solar energy while the engine is off & power is being drawn from the battery.

If you use a micro controller based smart charger with a good program, you should be able to do the following to determine the maximum safe voltage to apply to the battery while the engine is off:
1.  measure the battery V
2.  measure the A draw of the system
3.  To maintain the battery's current SOC, your power system must produce as much power as the system is consuming.  Your program would calculate the optimal charge A & V to provide sufficient charge current to offset the power consumption rate.
4.  To add a net charge increase in the battery, your computer program will have to provide a higher charge rate than the charge consumption rate (you can decide that rate or make it a user configurable parameter).

Note: The regulated charging system of a running vehicle provides sufficient power to charge the battery & maintain other electrical loads.  Your smart charger will have to emulate the same power availability while the engine is off (which might mean you'll need quite a bit of PV surface area (depending on loads).